# Heyzap SDK Unity Integration error - missing google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, heyzap, android-unity-plugin

I'm trying to integrate Heyzap 9.6.0(beta) in my Unity project. When trying to setup android, getting error:

Google Play Services lib project not found at: C:/Android/sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

I've checked my Android SDK, the revision of Google Play services is 30.
How can I setup Heyzap for android? Do I need to find and copy this lib manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Install the latest unitypackage release of the official google ads plugin here.](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases)

Heyzap is removing the bundled google-play-services from their unity plugin very soon.  You may also need to edit existing `AndroidManifest.xml` files in  your project and remove the following tag wherever it occurs to avoid conflicts with the official plugin:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

---

*EDIT*: There may be some complications, you'll need to do the following:

1. remove `Assets/Plugins/Android/google-play-services_lib` if it exists (or any other imported `google-play-services_lib` folders in your project)
2. remove these tags from any `AndroidManifest.xml` files in your project:

   ```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
   ```

   3. install the official google ads unity plugin from https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/download/v3.0.4/GoogleMobileAds.unitypackage
   4. remove the file at `Assets/Plugins/Android/GoogleMobileAdsPlugin/libs/PLUGIN_JAR_GOES_HERE`

**Source**: Engineer at Heyzap.

Comment: Thanks a lot Emory for your answer. Does it mean, that I should skip Android Setup for 9.6.0(beta) version and just remove that line from my AndroidManifest.xml files?

Comment: @HaykGeghamyan I edited my original response as I had some issues myself converting an existing project.